# The proof of perfect square having $0,1,4,5,6,9$ as units digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

To prove this, we defined $n$ as an integer, then said that it must have the form: $n= 10k +b$ where $b=0,1,....,9$

This is the step that I didn't get, why this integer has to have this form to prove that a perfect square has $0,1,4,5,6,9$ as ones digit ?

Answer (score 1):

This form is needed to be able to separate the ones digit from the rest of the number.

If $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $n$ can be written in the form $n=10k+b$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\{0,1,2,\ldots, 9\}$.

Now taking the square of $n$ gives

$$
n^2=(10k+b)^2=100k^2+20kb+b^2\equiv_{10}b^2.
$$

So the last digit of $n^2$ is the last digit of the square of $b$ and since $b$ is a digit it can only be *ten* different things. So it is deffinitely doable by hand.

> $$0^2\equiv_{10}0\\1^2\equiv_{10}1\\ 2^2\equiv_{10}4\\ 3^2\equiv_{10}9\\ 4^2\equiv_{10}6\\ 5^2\equiv_{10}5\\6^2\equiv_{10}6\\ 7^2\equiv_{10}9\\ 8^2\equiv_{10}4\\ 9^2\equiv_{10}1 $$

Answer (score 0):

We, human, have ten fingers, and the last digit of a perfect square is *never* 2, 3, 7, or 8. Indeed,

$$n^2 = (10k + b)^2 = 100k^2 + 20kb + b^2 \equiv b^2 \mod 10$$